# npm tough-cookie: save a cookie and then dump it

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, npm-request

I want to do a very simple task:

1. make an http `request` (`npm install request`) to
   `http://google.com` and save its cookie to `cookiejar`
2. see a list of cookies in `cookiejar` in the console to verify that
   the cookie is indeed there
3. dump all cookies from `cookiejar` and get some sort of confirmation that it's done (like `console.log('no errors')`)

Having gone through the docs for [tough-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tough-cookie), I'm having trouble with steps 2 and 3, in that 2 just shows an empty array and 3 throws out `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

My code below:

```
//npm install request
var request = require('request');

//special request that puts cookies in cookiejar
var cookieRequest = request.defaults( { jar : cookiejar } )

//npm install tough-cookie
var tough = require('tough-cookie');

//request the Store API
var store = tough.Store
var Cookie = tough.Cookie;

var cookiejar = new tough.CookieJar();

//load up google.com, I assume google would set some cookies in cookiejar
cookieRequest("http://google.com",function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode==200){
        console.log("requestDone")
    }
});

//request to see the cookies in cookiejar - at the moment it's returning an empty array, 
//would have expected something like ['cookie' : data ]
cookiejar.getCookies("http://google.com",function(err,cookies){
    console.log(cookies)
});

//here I want to dump whatever cookies were stored in cookiejar - at the moment this is 
//throwing a 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' and can't figure out why
cookiejar.store.removeCookies("http://google.com",function(err){
    console.log(err)
});
```

Also FYI the docs for [npm-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 2 years old, but I've been trying to figure out the answer to this question as well. I think i know the solution. Try this instead:

```
cookiejar._jar.store.removeCookies(...)
```

Comment: Cool thanks tons for sharing - it’s been too long for me to remember the gist of this so I won’t mark as completed to be safe but I have voted.  If anyone can comment whether this works for them I’ll lock in as the answer